# I am new to Facebook SDK with iOS. I want to send invitation to friends on Facebook

Tags: ios, facebook

1. When we run the code then the following error arrive
2. Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'com.facebook.sdk:InvalidOperationException', reason: 'FBSession: No AppID provided; either pass an AppID to init, or add a string valued key with the appropriate id named FacebookAppID to the bundle *.plist'

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
- (id)initWithAppId:(NSString *)app_id
    andDelegate:(id<FBSessionDelegate>)delegate;
```

use this link [use this link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/iossdk/authentication/)

Comment: Please help my currier depend on that app,if  i will not complete  this  task then i will fire by my company today

Comment: no sir ,sir am also provide app id displayname url but the problem has not solved ,sir after runing the flowing error arrive "Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'com.facebook.sdk:InvalidOperationException', reason: 'FBSession: No AppID provided; either pass an AppID to init, or add a string valued key with the appropriate id named FacebookAppID to the bundle *.plist'"

Comment: its means you have not added FacebookAppID show your plist

Comment: look at this https://docs.mobage.com/display/WWNATIVE23/Integrating+the+Facebook+SDK#IntegratingtheFacebookSDK-Step2

Answer (score 0):

You're missing FacebookAppID here, add your Id as mentioned in screenshot:

[image]

Comment: sir What is bundle id how we can provide

Comment: To authenticate your iOS app to use facebook, you need to create an app on developer.facebook.com 
http://ezibyte.com/how-to-setup-facebook-app-for-ios-application-or-game/

Comment: sir i have also created an app whit id on developer.facebook.com