# Can't get native login to work with Facebook iOS SDK

Tags: ios, facebook, xamarin

I'm using the [Facebook iOS SDK](https://components.xamarin.com/view/facebookios) component. On the top of the page, it says:

> **Native Facebook Login**, which is the first step in using Facebook to
>   drive user engagement and app installs.

All I get when I try to use this control is the WebView. I've looked into the Facebook iOS SDK to find that Native is the first prompt it tries, but I've used "OpenWithBehavior" to be sure we ignore WebView entirely, with no change. I've double- and triple-checked the AppID and DisplayName being used and they are both correct. I can login successfully using the WebView, I just can't get it to launch into the native app on my phone.

I know our app is configured correctly for Facebook login to work, because the app we have currently published on the App Store has native Facebook login.

This has been checked on two different iOS devices, both with Facebook installed. We've also tried reinstalling Facebook and trying both the default FBLoginView element included with the component as well as our own custom button.

I have no idea how to proceed. Can anyone provide any help or further ideas for what we could troubleshoot?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you allowed your app to access Facebook in Settings -> Facebook on the iPhone?

Comment: I don't see my app in that list at all, but the app is listed on the Facebook website as being approved.

Comment: If your app isn't on that list it means that your app hasn't requested for use of the user's Facebook account (in a native fashion).  Can you post your code?  That will make it easier.

Comment: Happy to post code that could help make this a little faster, but what code are you looking for specifically? I'm using the exact setup from the Facebook iOS SDK. So my AppDelegate.cs has my AppID and DisplayName, and I'm just using the native LoginView with those basic permissions to try to login to Facebook. It works, but only in WebView. If you could use any specific example I'm happy to post, I just don't really have any code other than my two keys in FBSettings and the opening of an FBLoginView.

Comment: Ah, also, just to add, the app isn't listed in my iPhone's settings, nor any one of my coworkers' iPhones, but we've used our existing app with native FB login (non-Xamarin) for some time. If the issues is that it isn't listed in settings, why would the old app not be listed? Additionally, there are several apps that use native login on my iPhone that i'm not seeing in this list...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get authenticated from the native facebook app, you need to FacebookAppID and url type in info.plist file, make sure you're using same bundle identifier as you mentioned in facebook app settings.

Check screenshot:
[I am new to Facebook SDK with iOS. I want to send invitation to friends on Facebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24094060/i-am-new-to-facebook-sdk-with-ios-i-want-to-send-invitation-to-friends-on-faceb/24094563#24094563)

Comment: I have tried manually editing my Info.plist file for Xamarin and have had no success. I've posted screenshots of what I've tried within the Info.plist on the Xamarin forums in [this post](http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/22777/can-t-get-native-login-to-work-with-facebook-ios-sdk).

Comment: Solution I posted for mainly native XCode project, I'm not sure if it'll work on Xamarin or not.

Comment: @Receme We did have this working at some point, but we ditched Xamarin in favor of native development several months ago.